# AT commands Get Request to server

Tags: nginx, server, webserver, at-command

I'm trying to make a Get request to a page hosted in a server with nginx.
I'm connecting to it with `AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.1.103",80` and the `AT+CIPSEND=<length>`.

After this I'm sending `http://192.168.1.103/?var1=val1&var2=val2`.

It returns a bad request error (400).

I've also tried with `GET /?var1=val1&var2=val2 HTTP/1.1`, but it doesn't return anything.

The web page is made via ExpressJS with `app.get('/', ...)` hosted with localhost and then passed to nginx via proxy_pass.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to construct the `http` yourself? If so, then for training, or practical reasons? What is your goal?